# Listview and OnItemClickListener(Bluetooth device)

Tags: java, android, listview, bluetooth

I have a problem with OnItemClickListener.
For example, i have 4 bluetooth devices in the list,i click on one element and the application try to pair only with the last element of the list not with the element that i clicked

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
            final BluetoothDevice device = intent
                .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n"
                    + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
            }
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id){
                    String devicep=listView.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString();
                    Log.i("device",devicep);
                    pairDevice(device);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice b1) {
        try {
            Method method = b1.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            method.invoke(b1, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because you have saved the last discovered device in the variable 'device' and in your on ListView onItemClick you are calling pairDevice(device), irrespective of the position of item being clicked.

You may want to save all the broadcasted discovered devices in a list and get the corresponding device object from the list according to the item clicked , something like this:

```
private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {
        final BluetoothDevice device = intent
            .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the recently discovered device in a list
            mDevices.add(bluetoothDevice);
            mDeviceList.add(bluetoothDevice.getName() + "\n"
                + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int pos, long id){
                String devicep=listView.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString();
                Log.i("device",device);
                // Get the BluetoothDevice corresponding to the clicked item
                pairDevice(mDevices.get(position));
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onItemClick you are not doing anything with the listitem you clicked on. You need to get the item from the list and pair that.

```
BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice) listView.getAdapter().getItem(pos);
                pairDevice(bluetoothDevice);
```

Try that and tell me if it works.

Comment: no, it does not work ,the app crashes because the casting is not allowed

Comment: Ah I see it now, I thought your deviceList was a list of BluetoothDevices instead of strings, changing that to BluetoothDevice and adding bluetoothdevices to the list should make my code work.